# R Apriori algorithm - how to assign top items values of ItemsFrequency() function to a vector?

Tags: r, apriori

Hello i am working in **Rpriori**. In this algorithum we use **itemFrequency()** function which return top items from data.Now i want to get the **value** of top items. not a
labels. and assign it to a vector.Thanks in advance

Remember:name argument give the name of the top items.only need has value!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will return the numeric vector containing names and values.

```
items <- itemFrequency(myTransactionsData, type = "absolute")
head(sort(items, decreasing = TRUE), n = 20)
```

But if you want only the value then try something like this

```
print(items[["whole milk"]])
Output: 2513
```